# Is it possible to overwrite gatsby-theme-blog's fonts?

Tags: gatsby, theme-ui

I am using gatsby-theme-blog, and would like to use fonts other than default "Montserrat" which comes with "Wordpress 2016" theme.

If possible, I'd like to change fonts to "Work Sans", which is used by "[fairyGate](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js/tree/master/packages/typography-theme-fairy-gates)" theme for headers.

From [Shadowing in Gatsby Themes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/themes/shadowing/#shadowing-example) I know how to create files under my projects to replace original files. However, all approaches have failed and the headings in Posts page stays `Montserrat`.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Install theme and its dependent typeface:

```json
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@theme-ui/typography": "^0.3.0", // to use `toTheme` method
    "typeface-work-sans": "^0.0.72", // the font I'd like to use
    "typography-theme-fairy-gates": "^0.16.19"
  }
}
```

2. Create files to shadow original typography:

```js
// my-project/src/gatsby-theme-blog/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/typography.ts

import "typeface-work-sans"

import { toTheme } from "@theme-ui/typography"
import fairyGates from "typography-theme-fairy-gates"

export default toTheme(fairyGates)
```

```js
// my-project/src/gatsby-theme-blog/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/index.ts


/* I duplicate most codes in original gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/index.js 
   intentionally to avoid other possible failing factors */

import merge from "deepmerge"
import typography from "gatsby-theme-blog/src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/typography"
import colors from "gatsby-theme-blog/src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/colors"
import styles from "gatsby-theme-blog/src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/styles"
import prism from "gatsby-theme-blog/src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/prism"

export default merge(typography, {
  initialColorMode: `light`,
  colors,
  fonts: {
    heading: `Work Sans, sans-serif`, // <- Changing font here doesn't work as expected!
    monospace: `Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, source-code-pro, Courier New, monospace`,
  },
  sizes: {
    container: 672,
  },
  styles,
  prism,
})
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a layout file and wrap all your pages inside of it. 
   Something like [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/layout-components/) could work
2. Use [CSS in JS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/css-modules/) to scope your styles or something similar where you can specify the font-style and override css styles in a scoped and modular way
3. Use [Gatsby plugin google fonts](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/?=google%20font) to bring your choice of fonts

Comment: Thank you! 1. and 2 are what I did (sorry for not clarifying this in post), but I didn't know there is Gatsby plugin google fonts. I'll go try, thanks!

Comment: Yes i definitely recommend Gatsby Google Fonts Plugin, It is very handy. Please accept this as the answer if it help you!